# How to create a new table from existing table with both keys and data in SQL Server 2012 (Management Studio)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

How can I create a new table from an existing one in SQL Server 2012 , with both  its keys and its data ?

This :

```
select * into New_Table
from Old_Table
```

Does not create the dependencies .

And this :

> In Sql Server Managment Studio, right-click your existing table and
>   select Script Table as > Create to > New Query Editor Window

Doesn't get the data .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following instructions work well if you want a GUI based solution and are dealing with a moderate amount of data.

1. In SSMS, right-click on the database that contains the table and select `Generate Scripts`
2. Select the specific table(s) to recreate

   [image: Choose objects]
3. Select the `Save to new query window` radio button and click `Advanced` to set scripting options for the table

   [image: Advanced scripting options]
4. Set the `Types of data to script` property to `Schema and data`

   [image: Types of data to script]
5. Modify the table name in the resulting script as appropriate

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use something like SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). This is a free, Microsoft, add-on to Visual Studio 2012/2013 (which you don't need to own). This tool will do schema and data compares. So all dependencies and schema objects will be created for you, in the correct order.